# DebugActiveProcess instead WriteProcessMemory

Tags: c++, winapi

I noticed that DebugActiveProcess let your process be a debugger to another process.
I saw that this function let you know the following events of the debuggee : Exception, Createthread, CreateProcess, ExitThread, ExitProces, LoadDll, UnloadDll, OutputDebugString.
My question is if we can write to the memory of the debuggee process without WriteProcessMemory? Is the debugger exists in the context memory of the debuggee?

Thanks!

Comment: What's `WriteProcsesMemory` anyway?

Comment: @IInspectable: Pretty hard to work out, I know.

Comment: @Jonathan: It may not be hard to work out for you. However, when it comes to discoverability, it is not just a typo. It's an information barrier. It will not show up in SO's search, it will not be readily available in the *mark as duplicate* dialog, etc. If the question were any good I would have edited it myself. Since it isn't I tried to get the OP's attention.

Answer (score 2):

A debugger exists in a different process from its debuggee. So you will need to use `ReadProcessMemory` and `WriteProcessMemory` to access the debuggee's address space.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you inject code into the process you're interested in, those are two different processes: one is the debugger and one is the debuggee.

You can either launch the debuggee via [CreateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)(cfr. [process creation flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx)) or attach your debugger to an existing one but they remain two different entities anyway and you'll have to use [WriteProcessMemory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681674(v=vs.85).aspx) to write to it.

It's the operating system which provides the API to operate your debugging on the target process (and you should make sure you have privileges to do that).